# How to use the constant outcome of a random formed function in python

Tags: python, random

let's look at the example blow

```
import numpy as np

def Test2(t):                     
    ran=np.random.randint(5)
    return t-ran

def Test3(t):                     
    test2=Test2(t)
    return t**2-test2

a1=Test3(1.0)                    
a2=Test3(1.0)
a3=Test3(1.0)
print(a1==a2,a1==a3,a2==a3)
```

the answer is false, since every time when i call Test3() it goes through the random part in Test2() and give me a different result. So how can i use the same Test3() for further calculating, that means i only want go through once Test2() and get a constant Test3().
Because i need Test3() for more calculating for instance finding roots, that means i need to call Test3() many times later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. All methods below will print `(True, True, True)`

### With a Class

```
import numpy as np

class TestClass:

    def __init__(self):
        self.test2out = None

    def Test2(self, t):                     
        ran=np.random.randint(5)
        return t-ran

    def Test3(self, t):
        if self.test2out is None:
            self.test2out = self.Test2(t)
        return t**2-self.test2out


testClass = TestClass()

a1=testClass.Test3(1.0)                    
a2=testClass.Test3(1.0)
a3=testClass.Test3(1.0)

print(a1==a2,a1==a3,a2==a3)
```

---

### With Memoizing

```
import numpy as np

def memoize(function):
    """Provides a decorator for memoizing functions"""
    from functools import wraps
    memo = {}
    @wraps(function)
    def wrapper(*args):
        if args in memo:
            return memo[args]
        else:
            rv = function(*args)
            memo[args] = rv
            return rv
    return wrapper

@memoize
def Test2(t):                     
    ran=np.random.randint(5)
    return t-ran

def Test3(t):
    test2 = Test2(t)
    return t**2-test2


a1=Test3(1.0)                    
a2=Test3(1.0)
a3=Test3(1.0)
print(a1==a2,a1==a3,a2==a3)
```

Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization)

---

### With Global Variable

```
import numpy as np

test2outcome = None

def Test2(t):                     
    ran=np.random.randint(5)
    return t-ran

def Test3(t): 
    global test2outcome   
    if test2outcome is None:
        test2outcome = Test2(t)
    return t**2-test2outcome

a1=Test3(1.0)                    
a2=Test3(1.0)
a3=Test3(1.0)
print(a1==a2,a1==a3,a2==a3)
```

Comment: Would you recommend this as a general solution for a project with many functions? Just because it "works" doesn't make it good. Global variables should be used sparingly, if at all.

Comment: I would assume a bigger project with many functions would use a class to hold these functions, and therefore could use class variables instead of global.

Comment: @SamHollenbach Could you give me an example how the class can handle these random formed function? Or some related material or resources? Thanks!

Comment: @IvyGao updated with a method using classes and one using memoizing

Answer (score 2):

Sam Hollenbach's solution is good but quite sophisticated given your very isolated problem.
I would recommend passing the random value as an argument to Test3.

```
import numpy as np

def Test2(t):                     
    ran=np.random.randint(5)
    return t-ran

def Test3(t, ran):
    return t**2-ran

ran = Test2(1.0)
a1=Test3(1.0, ran)                    
a2=Test3(1.0, ran)
a3=Test3(1.0, ran)
print(a1==a2,a1==a3,a2==a3)
```

This would isolate the randomness and is a little closer to the code you provided than creating a class for it.

Answer (score 1):

You could seed the random generator in Test3. This ensures that Test3 is predictable, while keeping the pseudo-randomness of Test2:

```
import numpy as np

def Test2(t):                     
    ran=np.random.randint(5)
    return t-ran

def Test3(t):
    np.random.seed(0)                    
    test2=Test2(t)
    return t**2-test2

a1=Test3(1.0)                    
a2=Test3(1.0)
a3=Test3(1.0)
print(a1==a2,a1==a3,a2==a3)
```